# VBA Importing multiple XML children under a single parent node

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I'm trying to import data from a XML response into an excel sheet and I am having difficulty with repeated child nodes under a single parent node. I need to be able to import the CategoryID, CategoryName, and CategoryParentName lines for each category. I've been able to get the first two but cant figure out the CategoryParentName since its repeated. The XML is as follows.

```html
<GetSuggestedCategoriesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2010-01-19T22:08:02.568Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>647</Version>
  <Build>E647_CORE_BUNDLED_10438248_R1</Build>
  <SuggestedCategoryArray>
    <SuggestedCategory>
      <Category>
        <CategoryID>18871</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Memory Cards</CategoryName>
        <CategoryParentID>625</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentID>3327</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentID>18866</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentName>Cameras & Photo</CategoryParentName>
        <CategoryParentName>Camera Accessories</CategoryParentName>
        <CategoryParentName>Digital Camera Accessories</CategoryParentName>
      </Category>
      <PercentItemFound>4</PercentItemFound>
    </SuggestedCategory>
    <SuggestedCategory>
      <Category>
        <CategoryID>48629</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Color</CategoryName>
        <CategoryParentID>293</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentID>14948</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentID>48633</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentID>48638</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentID>48628</CategoryParentID>
        <CategoryParentName>Electronics</CategoryParentName>
        <CategoryParentName>Gadgets</CategoryParentName>
        <CategoryParentName>Surveillance</CategoryParentName>
        <CategoryParentName>Surveillance Cameras</CategoryParentName>
        <CategoryParentName>Wired Cameras</CategoryParentName>
      </Category>
      <PercentItemFound>4</PercentItemFound>
    </SuggestedCategory>
```

Here's my attempt for the VBA code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
Sub CategoryResponse()
Outputrow = Sheet1.Range("E1") + 7
        
Nodes = "GetSuggestedCategoriesResponse/SuggestedCategoryArray/SuggestedCategory"
For Each CAT In responseItem.SelectNodes(Nodes)
   Outputcol = 3
   Sheet1.Range("A" & Outputrow).Value = CAT.SelectSingleNode("PercentItemFound").Text
   Sheet1.Range("B" & Outputrow).Value = CAT.SelectSingleNode("Category/CategoryID").Text
        
   Nodes1 = "GetSuggestedCategoriesResponse/SuggestedCategoryArray/SuggestedCategory/CategoryParentName"
   For Each PAR In responseItem.SelectNodes(Nodes1)
      Sheet1.Cells(Outputrow, Outputcol).Value = PAR.SelectSingleNode("CategoryParentName").Text
      Outputcol = Outputcol + 1
   Next PAR
   
   Sheet1.Cells(Outputrow, Outputcol).Value = UST.SelectSingleNode("Category/CategoryName").Text
   Outputrow = Outputrow + 1
Next UST

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nodes1` should be created relative to the current node in the `For Each CAT ...` loop and not relative to `responseItem`. Try:

```
Nodes1 = "Category/CategoryParentName"
For Each PAR In CAT.SelectNodes(Nodes1)
   Sheet1.Cells(Outputrow, Outputcol).Value = PAR.Text
   Outputcol = Outputcol + 1
Next PAR
```

You want to select the CategoryParentName nodes which relate to the current SuggestedCategory node. Your original code would have returned all of the CategoryParentNames (which matched the selectNodes expression) regardless of which SuggestedCategory node they related to

Comment: Thank you! I I can see what I was doing wrong now. The code works perfectly. Honestly this project is my first time coding other than arduino and labview so I really appreciate the help!